# CSS, overlap children div but the width of parent div stay the same

Tags: html, css, overlap

I would like to make an overlap of children div using `position:relative` and `left` attribute. Because of overlapping, I would like to reduce the parent width. However, in fact, the parent div does not reduced.
Here is my codepen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRMMwW

HTML

```
<div class="mother">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.mother {
  background-color: red;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div.child:nth-child(2) {
  left: -25px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.child:nth-child(3) {
  left: -50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

div.child:nth-child(4) {
  left: -75px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

[image: I would like to remove the exceed red section]

As you can see, the `mother` div width does not fit to its own children width and there is an exceed red section. I would like to remove the exceed red section. Do you know any solution here. One more point. I try to avoid `flex` and `float`.

## Update for Kumar why not reduce the width of children by half.

I suppose to make a cluster of image which overlap each other. Let imagine those `child` div is round border like this. As you can see, it's not a good idea to set the width of child to half.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [negative margins](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) on the inner divs (`margin-left: -25px`) while giving the parent div an offset margin - (`margin-left: 25px`)

```css
div.mother {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

div.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

div.child:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.child:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: pink;
}

div.child:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

This is also easy to animate in case you want to remove the overlap on `:hover`

*Rough animation draft:*

```css
div.mother {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
  z-index: 1; /* botttom layer */
}

div.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

div.child:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2; /* botttom layer +1 */
}

div.child:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: pink;
  z-index: 3; /* botttom layer +2 */
}

div.child:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 4; /* botttom layer +3 */
}

div.child:hover {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;  /*animation speed */
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* makes animation stop at 100% and not revet back to original state */
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.child:nth-child(4):hover {
  animation-name: none; /* doesn't need animation othewise you would see red background from parent div */
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 20px; /* pushes the next div out so you can see current div. */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your perfect question with margin tweak. In addition, the animation is so cool. Thank you again, you save my day.

Comment: @NguyenVinhLinh No problem. Happy to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `background:transparent` in `mother` css class.

```css
div.mother {
  background: transparent;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius:2em;
}

div.child:nth-child(2) {
  left: -25px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.child:nth-child(3) {
  left: -50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

div.child:nth-child(4) {
  left: -75px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your answer. I intent to do a cluster of image with round border. The `child` div will be an `img` tag. each image will be overlap by 30% to the left. As a consequence, I cannot make the reduce the width of child element as you said. I have update the image to visualize my idea in question.

Comment: please check the snippet once, here you want something like this but you don't want that `red background`. I have a question here if all the rounded images should fixed width with the background then does `background:transparent` helps you?